# Window resize at certain size

Tags: jquery, resize, window-resize

I am trying to write a JQuery function, so when I resize a window at 700px, I can remove a CSS class.

Is there any way I could do that?

Could someone point me to some resources or give me and example?

Answer (score 1):

1) Listen for resize event see http://api.jquery.com/resize/

E.g

```
 $( window ).resize(function() {
  $( "body" ).prepend( "<div>" + $( window ).width() + "</div>" );
});
```

2) Remove class  see http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/

E.g

```
$( "p" ).removeClass( "myClass yourClass" )
```

Answer (score 0):

Using two sets of CSS and use media query to listen to screen width might be easier and better. And gives you more control of style on smaller browser sizes and better result.